# Why doesn't animating combined scale and translate CGAffineTransform simply work?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

Can someone please explain why:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.333)
{
    self.someView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.3, y: 0.3).translatedBy(x: 100, y: 100)
}
```

does not work? The above immediately performs the translation; only the scaling is animated.

Also, why does [this dirty trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33465048/1971013) work?

Thanks!

Comment: About the "dirty trick" - You can open a bug at apple's bug reporter... And wait for response that will come about 50 years later

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide more code details? I was solved similar issue. In my situation the gesture delegate was applied to superview insted of subview. So translateBy applied to superview in gesture delegate does not affect expected subview. I solved it by delegate gesture recognizer for subview directly.

Comment: I my case the scaling worked, so I am no mixing up a view and superview. (BTW, this seems to be more a comment than an answer.)

Comment: Interesting case but I have no reputation for comment questions yet