# Is something different in iOS 14 with the way transforms are handled during a custom view controller presentation?

Tags: cgaffinetransform, uipresentationcontroller

As part of learning UIPresentationController (and its associated custom view controller presentation objects) I figured I'd recreate Apple's iOS 13 default modal presentation style. It worked well-enough on [iOS 12 and 13](https://reddit-uploaded-video.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/t2_oljwb%2F5mnp5s6ni2w51), but on iOS 14 I get [this weirdness](https://reddit-uploaded-video.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/t2_oljwb%2Fiw8w8q9wi2w51) (also note how when dismissing the presentingVC snaps to be proper position it's supposed to have). Did something change? The relevant code for the applied transform is:

```
let ratio = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 32) / UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let height = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView.height
let newHeight = height * ratio
let translation = (height - newHeight) / 2

return CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: ratio, y: ratio).concatenating(.init(translationX: 0, y: -translation - 10))
```

It's worth noting that presenting the first VC (which the video starts with it already presented) works just fine, as does presenting a new VC.

Edit: Resolved! Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33465048/5154869), turns out it's a bug with transforms.